# New to NoSQL, How do I get list of category names from a list of ids

Tags: database, nosql, redis

**My structure**

```
cat:id:name -> name of category
cat:id:subcats -> set of subcategories
cat:list -> list of category ids
```

The following gives me a list of cat ids:

```
lrange cat:list 0, -1
```

Do I have to iterate each id from the above command to get the `name` field in my script? Because that seems inefficient. How can I get a list of category names from redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple different approaches. You may want to have the values in the list be delimited/encoded strings that contain both the id, the name, and any other value you need quick access to. I recommend JSON for interoperability and efficient string length, but there are other formats which are more performant.

Another option is to, like you said, iterate. You can make this more efficient by getting all your keys in a single request and then using MGET, pipelining, or MULTI/EXEC to fetch all the names in a single, efficient, operation.